# How to construct literal value in Go of a complex/recursive object?

Tags: go

I'm a Go newbie and I'm having a hard time with syntax of complex objects.

I have the code below.

```
import {
    "fmt"
    gstruct "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/struct"
}

type MyType struct {
    Element []*gstruct.Struct
}

x := new(MyType)
x = // do something here that sets x.Element

fmt.Println("x.Element = ", x.Element)

var y []*gstruct.Struct
```

When I run this, the output is as follows:

> [fields:{key:"A" value:{list_value:{values:{struct_value:{fields:{key:"B" value:{string_value:"C"}} fields:{key:"D" value:{number_value:120}}}}}}}]

The definition of gstruct.Struct is [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/master/types/known/structpb/struct.pb.go#L190-L198):

```
type Struct = structpb.Struct

// The JSON representation for `Struct` is JSON object.
type Struct struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    // Unordered map of dynamically typed values.
    Fields map[string]*Value `protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=fields,proto3" json:"fields,omitempty" protobuf_key:"bytes,1,opt,name=key,proto3" protobuf_val:"bytes,2,opt,name=value,proto3"`
}
```

The definition of Value is [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/master/types/known/structpb/struct.pb.go#L280-L296):

```
// The JSON representation for `Value` is JSON value.
type Value struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    // The kind of value.
    //
    // Types that are assignable to Kind:
    //  *Value_NullValue
    //  *Value_NumberValue
    //  *Value_StringValue
    //  *Value_BoolValue
    //  *Value_StructValue
    //  *Value_ListValue
    Kind isValue_Kind `protobuf_oneof:"kind"`
}
```

Now I want to set the value of `y` as a literal such that y is equal to `x.Element`. However I don't want to simply assign `y = x`. How can I construct such a literal?

Comment: What is the definition of `gstruct.Struct`?

Comment: I added it in the question

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the non-exported fields `state`, `sizeCache`, and `unknownFields`. You can set the `Field` as:

```
y=[]*gstruct.Struct{{Fields:map[string]*gstruct.Value{"key":&gstruct.Value{...}}}}
```

You should look at the `Value` definition to figure out its exported fields, and set them

Comment: Can u show me precisely how to do it for the value of `x` that I have shown above?

Comment: Need to see the definition of `Value` as well

Comment: Added in the question above. I posted links to the source code so you can explore it.

Comment: @SaqibAli It is absolutely NOT possible to initialize unexported fields of imported struct types using only composite literal expressions. The most you can do with pure composite literal expression is to initialize a "skeleton" value initializing only those fields that *are* exported, i.e. `Struct.Fields` and `Value.Kind`, you simply cannot initialize any of the other fields with a composite literal. To fully initialize `y` you would have to combine the literal expression with call expressions to exported "constructor" functions provided by the imported type's package, *if there are any*.

Comment: @SaqibAli note also that the output of `fmt.Println("x.Element = ", x.Element)` is produced by the `String` method that both the `Struct` and the `Value` implement (the `fmt` package invokes the `String` method on almost all types that implement it). The output of `String` is usually intended to format the content of the receiver in a readable way, but it can be anything, it does not have to be, and in this case isn't, an exact word-for-word representation of the `struct` being printed.

Comment: mkopriva ok. How would I do specify only the exported fields to match the object shown in fmt.Println()?? I don't think the unexported fields are relevant to me.